# Using np.array the first to reference the values in the second

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a reference np.array that describes where to find attributes:

```
ref =
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]
 [13 14 15]
 [16 17 18]
 [19 20 21]
 [22 23 24]
 [25 26 27]
 [28 29 30]
 [31 32 33]
 [34 35 36]]
```

I want to find the value for "8" from the value table with the same address as the ref table [2,1]

The values table example:

```
value =
[[ 3.  6.  0.]
 [ 5.  2.  2.]
 [ 5.  4.  4.]
 [ 6.  5.  7.]
 [ 4.  9.  8.]
 [ 5.  6.  6.]
 [ 5.  5.  5.]
 [ 6. 13.  6.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.]
 [ 7.  9.  7.]
 [ 4.  7.  1.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.]]
```

So, ref 8 received a value of 4.  Easy right?  But, I'm new to python.

My attempts of np.where's aren't working so well.  "Test" is the specific reference of 8.

```
address = np.asarray(np.where(ref == test)).transpose() #get the addresses of variable test=8 as an example => [2,1]
val = value[address] #looking for value at address value[2,1] = 4
```

I ultimately would like to take a vector array, find the addresses in the value array and, sum the values.
 sum [ 7  8 10 11] --> sum of values at ([2,0],[2,1],[3,0],[3,1]) => sum(5,4,6,5) = 20

Alternatively, you could also tempt me to do a 3D array on reference to map to values if you prompt me in the right direction.

Comment: Don't you just want `value[np.where(ref == 8)]`?

Comment: i already added a code  in witch i answer your questions about how to replace an element in the same position with the content of the first array  element  then i add anther code in witch you can get the sum of cells from the array and finally  i added anther code that give you the index's takes by a given member from the array

Answer (score 0):

- try this as a response of your first question : "ref 8 received a value of 4"

  ```
  import numpy as np
      # Create a 2D Numpy array from list of lists
      ref = np.array(
      [[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7 , 8  ,9],
       [10 ,11 ,12],
       [13 ,14 ,15],
       [16 ,17 ,18],
       [19 ,20 ,21],
       [22 ,23 ,24],
       [25 ,26 ,27],
       [28 ,29 ,30],
       [31 ,32 ,33],
       [34 ,35, 36]])

      value = np.array(
      [[3,  6,  0],
       [5,  2,  2],
       [5,  4,  4],
       [6,  5,  7],
       [4,  9,  8],
       [5,  6,  6],
       [5,  5,  5],
       [6, 13,  6],
       [4,  4,  4],
       [7,  9,  7],
       [4, 7,  1],
       [4,  4,  4]])
      l=list
      print('Contents of 2D Numpy Array ref ', ref, sep='\n')
      print('index of your element in your example  X=2 : ')
      x=int(input())
      print('index of your element in your example Y=1 : ')
      y=int(input())
      res=value[x][y]            
      ref[x][y]=res
      print('Contents of 2D Numpy Array ref after modification', ref, sep='\n')
  ```

Sum of the row by giving the index x and y of every element in the row for example row [3,6,0] will be 0,0 0,1 0,2 ...

```
import numpy as np

    value = np.array(
    [[3,  6,  0],
     [5,  2,  2],
     [5,  4,  4],
     [6,  5,  7],
     [4,  9,  8],
     [5,  6,  6],
     [5,  5,  5],
     [6, 13,  6],
     [4,  4,  4],
     [7,  9,  7],
     [4, 7,  1],
     [4,  4,  4]])
    res=list()
    print('member of element to count : ')
    z=int(input())
    for i in range(z):
        print('index x of element : ' +str(i))
        x=int(input())
        print('index y  of element : ' +str(i))
        y=int(input())
        res.append(value[x][y])
        print(res)
    print('SUM', sum(res))
```

finnaly to get the list of index's that your element exist try this code :

```
import numpy as np

value = np.array(
[[3,  6,  0],
 [5,  2,  2],
 [5,  4,  4],
 [6,  5,  7],
 [4,  9,  8],
 [5,  6,  6],
 [5,  5,  5],
 [6, 13,  6],
 [4,  4,  4],
 [7,  9,  7],
 [4, 7,  1],
 [4,  4,  4]])


print('Enter element from the array  : ')
res = int(input())

result = np.where(value == res)
print('Tuple of arrays returned : ', result)
print('List of coordinates where element with value 15 exists in given 2D array : ')
# zip the 2 arrays to get the exact coordinates
listOfCoordinates = list(zip(result[0], result[1]))
# iterate over the list of coordinates
for cord in listOfCoordinates:
    print(cord)


print("*** Get the index of an element based on multiple conditions Numpy Array ***")
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ref` and `value` are `numpy.ndarray` of the same shapes, the following function should work the same whether it is 2D or 3D (provided `ref` has unique elements like `1 .. ref.size`)

```py
import numpy as np

ref = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18],
       [19, 20, 21],
       [22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27],
       [28, 29, 30],
       [31, 32, 33],
       [34, 35, 36]])

value = np.array([[ 3.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 5.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  5.,  7.],
       [ 4.,  9.,  8.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  6.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 6., 13.,  6.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 7.,  9.,  7.],
       [ 4.,  7.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.]])


def f(references):
    # expecting either a number or a list of numbers
    # so when a single number is provided simply make it a list
    if isinstance(references, int) or isinstance(references, float):
        references = [references]

    # create a generator for each reference point
    positions = (np.where(ref == reference) for reference in references)

    """
    If you want the values directly as numbers then use the .item() method like so
    return (value[position].item() for position in positions)
    """
    return (value[position] for position in positions)
```

If you wanted to find sum of the values referenced at [7, 8, 10, 11] you could just do

```py
sum(f([7, 8, 10, 11]))
```

Output: `array([20.])`

Or to see the values just do `list(f([7, 8, 10, 11]))` to get `[array([5.]), array([4.]), array([6.]), array([5.])]`

But see the line where you can use `(value[position].item() for position in positions)` instead and everything will be a number.

```py
def g(references):
    # expecting either a number or a list of numbers
    # so when a single number is provided simply make it a list
    if isinstance(references, int) or isinstance(references, float):
        references = [references]

    # create a generator for each reference point
    positions = (np.where(ref == reference) for reference in references)

    return (value[position].item() for position in positions)
```

`sum(g([7, 8, 10, 11]))` -> `20.0`
`list(g([7, 8, 10, 11]))` -> `[5.0, 4.0, 6.0, 5.0]`